# Is this the official Marie Curie postdoc fellowship applicant guide?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job, marie-curie

I'm a new Mare Cure fellowship applicant and I'm getting overwhelmed by the information  online and trying to find the quickest way to understand what I need to know and do as an applicant so that I get to the stage of building the actual proposal. In this regard, I'm just checking with you to see if the following guide is official and is something that every applicant should read first: https://rea.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2023-04/Guide%20for%20applicants_MSCA%20PF%202023.pdf?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there anything in particular about the document that makes you suspect that it is a highly elaborate hoax uploaded to the official website of the European Research Executive Agency by malicious hackers, rather than what it claims to be on the first page, namely a "guide [that] aims to support potential applicants to the PF 2023 call"?

Comment: @AdamPřenosil Thank you, and sorry for asking the obvious - I'll start reading this guide now :)